# Customized UITableViewCell didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

I have a customized UITableViewCell that contains a few textviews and one imageview. These views are non-selectable (set in IB). I hope that didSelectRowAtIndexPath is triggered when users tap anywhere inside the cell. However, I find that it is not triggered when tapping on these views, even though these views are "in" the side. Looks like the "tapped" event is intercepted by these views. How can I make these views "no-tappable"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
textView.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Or uncheck "User Interaction Enabled" in IB:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Bannings's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31978221/3326630) seems corrected.

In other case, a workaround is using `UITapGestureRecognizer` (either on UITableView, UITableViewCell or UIView) to know if a cell was tapped, then call `-selectRowAtIndexPath:` on UITableView.

Comment: Thank you too for your answers!!